# How to draw [ Vertical and Stacked ] bar chart in Prime faces

Tags: primefaces, jqplot

I need to draw vertical and stacked bar chart using prime faces.

You can find horizontal and stacked bar chart and below link

https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chart/bar.xhtml

I have requirement of Vertical and Stacked bar chart.

I have already tried all google links. No output.

Comment: Start by correcly tagging the question. Learn what PF uses for its charts, And according to [ask], if you search and found sort of relevant questions that did not help, mention them... Now it is 'Please do all the work for me' question. Cheers

Comment: Expert thanks for your reply.
No relevant question found. So no point of mentioning what did not help.
And please do not do all the work for me,.
This question is for someone who has already done it he can easily understand and answer quickly.

Comment: Good luck then... I think you just mis shundreds of experts by not adding good tags to your question (and stand a chance of getting downvotes by ones following the wrongly added tags)... Let me correct them for you, for once. And really... **all** google links??? Wow...

Comment: And did you actually not try using `setStacked(true)` on the BarChartModel like they do on the HorizontalBarChartModel???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use

```
setStacked(true);
```

on your BarChartModel.

**See also**

- https://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/6.1/org/primefaces/model/chart/BarChartModel.html#setStacked-boolean-
- https://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_1.pdf#95

Comment: So you tried every google link but not the PF docs or simple code completion in the IDE? I think such help also deserves an upvote ;-)